# How to I do This but for 16 more (sorry about the mess)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use this code for all the names and not do one sepret everytime

html code:

```
<div id="one" class="text-container"> 
  <span> Campfire Cooking in Another World with my Absurd Skill</span> 
  <div class="fader fader-left"></div>
  <div class="fader fader-right"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
let container1 = document.querySelector("#one");
let text1 = document.querySelector("#onespan");

if (container1.clientWidth < text1.clientWidth) { 
  text1.classList.add("animate"); 
}
```

I tried that code but it one does one name and not the rest.

Comment: try to add your code in a code block or a snippet

Comment: For one thing, you have no element with the id `onespan`. Are the "16 more" already generated in the html?

Comment: yes there are 16 more of the html already generated

Comment: the (onespan) should be (one span)

Comment: A.) IDs should not have spaces. B.) there is still no element with id = "one span"

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this help?

```
let container = document.querySelectorAll(".text-container");
let text = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (let i=0; i<container.length; i++) {
  if (container[i].clientWidth < text[i].clientWidth) {
    text[i].classList.add("animate");
  }
}
```

Comment: ir still only moves the one and not the rest

Comment: Are you sure you also changed `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll`? I would suggest you to add the code where you have the 16 more items you  are talking about

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix

Instead of doing a `querySelector` based one element using its ID. We can query multiple elements using `querySelectorAll` and do a query based a class, since an ID should one be used once.

```js
    // this will get all the 16 elements, as long as they use this class.
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".text-container"); 
    
    
    for (let i=0; i<containers.length; i++) {
      // for each container we will need to find its text element we want to animate
      const text = containers[i].querySelector("span");

      if (containers[i].clientWidth < text.clientWidth) {
        text.classList.add("animate");
      }
    }
```

instead of using a for loop you could also use a `forEach` which many people prefer as it easier to read. If you like the for loop more, stick with that!

```js
    // this will get all the 16 elements, as long as they use this class.
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".text-container"); 
    
    containers.forEach((container) => {
        // for each container we will need to find its text element we want to animate
        const text = container.querySelector("span");
    
        if(container.clientWidth < text.clientWidth) {
          text.classList.add("animate");
        }
      })      
    }
```

#### Advice

I would recommend adding a specific class for those 16 elements that you won't accidentilly reuse. This could be more likely with a generic name like `.text-container` instead of going with something like `.js-animated-card`.

Adding `js-` as a prefix could help you easily separate the classes you use for styles and the classes you added to query the element in JS. This way you can also move/edit/rename you style classes without having the risk that you might break you javascript code.